# How to do calculation in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Here i have mentioned my html and my component.ts

My Question is that?

1. Here the **orginal amount** and **Open balance** auto populated
   from the database. payment is input field.
2. When the user enters the payment amount. The payment amount and Open 
   balance should add and subtract with Original amount that balance amount 
   should display in the  Balance Due column.

   This calculation should perform before the submit action.I dont know how to do that
   [image: Html screen]

**Html**

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align: center ">
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 40%">DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th style="width: 15%">DUE DATE</th>
                <th style="width: 15%">ORIGINAL AMOUNT</th>
                <th style="width: 15%">OPEN BALANCE</th>
                <th style="width: 15%">PAYMENT</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <textarea type="text" value="reset" class="form-control" id="description" disabled [(ngModel)]="model.description" style=" border-color: transparent"
                    name="description" #description="ngModel"></textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input #duedate="ngModel" type="date" class="form-control" disabled [(ngModel)]="billForm.duedate" required name="due_date"
                    id="due_date" style=" border-color: transparent">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" #refrence #originalamtInput="ngModel" disabled style=" border-color: transparent" class="form-control"
                    id="original_amount" [(ngModel)]="model.originalamtInput" name="original_amount">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" #refrence #openbalance="ngModel" disabled style=" border-color: transparent" class="form-control" id="open_balance"
                    style="border-color:transparent" [(ngModel)]="model.openbalance" name="open_balance">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" #refrence #paymentamount="ngModel" (keyup)="onKey(paymentamount.value)" style=" border-color: transparent"
                    style="text-align:right; border-color: transparent" placeholder="₹0.00" class="form-control" id="payment_amount"
                    pattern="[0-9]+" required minlength="0" maxlength="7" [(ngModel)]="model.paymentamount" name="payment_amount">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <b style=" text-align:right;padding-left: 10%;">Total&emsp;&emsp;₹ &ensp;{{this.total }}</b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div style="padding-left: 50%;">
                <b>Balance due&emsp;₹ &ensp;&ensp;&ensp; &ensp;</b>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidateForm } from './validate';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PaymentsService } from "../payments.service";    
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToasterConfig, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { NotificationService } from '../../services/notification.service';
import 'style-loader!angular2-toaster/toaster.css';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-popovers',
  styleUrls: ['./new-payments.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './new-payments.component.html',
})
export class NewPaymentComponent {
  total: any;
  toastConfig: ToasterConfig;
  today: number = Date.now();

  payservice: PaymentsService

  register = true;
  selectedFile = null;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private paymentsService: PaymentsService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private toasterService: ToasterService
  ) {      }

  model: ValidateForm[] = [];
 onChangePayment(event) {

    if (event.value === 'addpayment') {
      this.router.navigate(['/pages/payment/payment']);
    }
  }

  onKey(amountInput) {
    this.total = amountInput

  }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing difficult in this simply in your method you just need to assign value after calculation and assign it to some variable like this -

```
<div style="padding-left: 50%;">
  <b>Balance due&emsp;₹ &ensp;&ensp;&ensp; &ensp; {{balance_due}}</b>
</div>

onKey(amountInput) {
  this.balance_due = (amountInput + this.model.openbalance) - this.model.originalamtInput
}
```

Comment: if i try this it shows error like openbalance does not exist on type validateform.

Comment: so must know what is the variable name for the same to get values and do corresponding calculations

Answer (score 0):

You can go with typescript class properties;

```
 <td>
 <input type="text" #refrence #paymentamount="ngModel" (keyup)="onKey(paymentamount.value)" style=" border-color: transparent"
                style="text-align:right; border-color: transparent" placeholder="₹0.00" class="form-control" id="payment_amount"
                pattern="[0-9]+" required minlength="0" maxlength="7" [(ngModel)]="model.paymentamount" name="payment_amount">
            </td>

get paymentamount():number{
       return  _paymentamount;
}
set paymentamount(val:number){
     if(val===this._paymentamout) return;
     this._paymentamount=val;
     this.calculate();// Calculation logic go
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the demo, and make the changes accordingly.
Please confirm, you want to subtract the sum amount from the Original amount or you want to subtract the original amount from the sum.

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q1)

Hope this will help you.